# Failed to save undefined: The attribute "onactive" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:tab: Source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, action, aura-attribute, spring17

I'm trying to create a lightning tabset through an iteration. 
Every tab should call the controller when clicked. The SFDC Doc tells, that the Action onactive can be used for this, but it does't recognize the attribute.

```
<lightning:tabset >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Items}" var="item" indexvar="index">
        <lightning:tab label="{!item}" onactive="{!c.tabClick}">
            <ui:outputtext value="{!item}" />
        </lightning:tab>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:tabset>
```

it says

> Failed to save undefined: The attribute "onactive" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:tab: Source

here is the link to the description

[lightning:tab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tab.htm)

[image]

am I using it wrong?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I just tried in my Spring '17 org and it's working fine, the `onActive` attribute of `lightning:tab`. @CarnVanBeck

Comment: Well that would explain my problem, my Orgs are still running on Winter'17 till next month.

Comment: I was also able to reproduce the same issue in Winter '17 org. But ideally, it should've worked in Winter '17 also since the `lightning:tab` component was there, though in Beta version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this attribute is only available in Spring'17 and not in Winter'17.

Thanks to @SE_User for the test.